# Too many texture accesses

Tags: opengles

Opengl ES 2.0, GLSL version 100.

I am using window (playing with 3x3 or 5x5, ...) in fragment shader, and was wondering what is the max number of texture accesses allowed?

Because when about ~ 50 texture reads, I get error noted in title above.